# What are some good books to read for understanding philosophy and life of Ramakrishna?

Tags: resource, ramakrishna

What are some good books to study Ramakrishna as I am a beginner and don't know much about him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His simple stories encapsulate his teachings in an accessible way:

http://yousigma.com/biographies/Tales%20and%20Parables%20of%20Sri%20Ramakrishna%20(English).pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer....Is Gospel of Ramakrishna a good book for beginners?

Comment: Its also good, perhaps read the tales and parables first - after all it is very entertaining also :-) Since the teachings are mostly non-scriptural (directly experienced) advaita by their very nature they cannot be intricate or elaborate. @Rishx

Comment: I agree...I will read his parables first.

Answer (score 4):

The Ramakrishna Mission has published the following books which are cosidered to be authentic, but only english translations of the first two are available on internet:

1.Sri Sri Ramakrishna-Kathamrita by M

2.Sri Sri Ramakrishna-Leelaprasanga by Swami Saradananda

3.Sri Ramaktprishnadeva by Sasibhushan Ghosh

4.Sri Sri Ramakrishnadever Jivanbrittanta by Ramchandra Dutta

5.Sri Ramakrishna-Puthi by Akshay Kumar Sen

6.Sri SrinRamakrishnadever Upadesha by Swami Brahmananda

The books written by disciples of Sri Ramakrishna, but not published by the Mission:

7.Sri Sri Ramakrishna-Leelamrita by Vaikunthanath Sannyal

8.Sri Sri Ramakrishnadever Upadesh by Suresh Chandra Dutta

The following books published by the Mission are also useful:

9.Sri Ramakrishner Antyaleela by Swami Prabhananda(Two Volumes)

Comment: Thanks....Isn't Ramakrishna Kathamrta same as Gospel of Ramakrishna?

Comment: I m not bengali..on little searching i found that gospel is not complete  translation of Ramakrishna Kathamrta..If so does a complete english translation exist?

Comment: No Problem...you shouldn't apologise. :-).I guess no matter how hard one try ..the true essence is lost in translation....

Comment: @Rishix There is a book by Swami Chetanananda :They lived with God. I think this book on Sri Ramakrishna u cd read.its a great book, a compilation

Comment: Ok I will def read it :)

Comment: Very nice answer! Btw do u have all the books u hv mentioned? @Partha

Comment: @Rickross only puthi and lilamrita i returned to lib:)

Comment: Grt .. so u basically rely on library or u buy the books as well? @Partha

Comment: @Rickross what i find worthy of keeping i buy:)

Comment: Haha that's the smart policy .. I shd be following the same @Partha

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the following books:

• [Sri Ramakrishna: The Great Master by Swami Saradananda](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://estudantedavedanta.net/Sri%2520Ramakrishna%2520-%2520The%2520Great%2520Master%2520by%2520Swami%2520Saradananda%2520%5B1080%2520Pages,%2520A%2520Detailed%2520Biography%5D%2520%25281%2529_r.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjU_aOA967gAhUFK48KHbOjBCQQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw0tKY0xgiXTGVx66IBFU9eR&cshid=1549725089911)

• [The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna by Mahendranath Gupta](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.vedanta-nl.org/GOSPEL.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjKiKq1967gAhXCtI8KHShEAxYQFjAAegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw3odWNJ6zArthIiJnL30dmD)

• [The Tales and Parables of Sri Ramakrishna](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://yousigma.com/biographies/Tales%2520and%2520Parables%2520of%2520Sri%2520Ramakrishna%2520(English).pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiBsdv4967gAhULu48KHfYyCt4QFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw3eSQoMaAf0-gIfD489OYkc&cshid=1549725133263)

• [Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsopanishad by C.Rajagopalachari](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://rkmathbangalore.org/Books/Vedanta%2520Kesari/(1985,%2520November-December).pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjR0eS3-K7gAhUDp48KHT2FBu0QFjACegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw02PgJH2-6DeunQIBRKZSCM)

Comment: Thanks for your answer...Which of these is good for beginners I have heard Gospel of Ramakrishna is little too deep....

Comment: @Rishx Yes, "Gospel of Ramakrishna" is definitely deep. The same goes for "Sri Ramakrishna: The Great Master". If you want to study his life first, go for the latter. As far as his teachings are concerned, go for "Tales and Parables of Sri Ramakrishna"

Comment: I guess I will first read his tales and parables.

Comment: I am downvoting beacuse paramahansopinishad is not an authentic text.Upanishads can not be written in this way.This goes against the sanatana dharma tradition.

Comment: @Partha It's published by RKM and endorsed by RKM gurus

Comment: does not matter:) its not authentic because upanishads are not composed but vedamantras.Sri Ramakrishna was God does not mean whatever their current followers do is right

Comment: @Partha They have never claimed it to be a real Upanishad. It is only called an Upanishad. Otherwise they wouldn't say it's written by C. Rajagopalachari. Nobody is claiming it to be a Veda mantra.

Comment: why shd some one dare to name something as Upanishads when its not? i value the kathamrita at per with original Upanishads personally, if not higher.But our tradition has been clear that Upanishads are visions of mantras by seers and not a constructed thing:)

Comment: the current commentary of Gita by the mission by Ranganathananda treats indian constitution as a sastra for example.can i support it being a hindu?

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting the latest online reading available officially on Ramakrishna Math's website:

- [A SHORT LIFE OF SRI RAMAKRISHNA](https://englishbooks.rkmm.org/s/lsr/m/a-short-life-of-sri-ramakrishna/a/cover)
- [SRI RAMAKRISHNA LIFE AND TEACHINGS by Swami Tapasyananda - study and interpretation of Sri Ramakrishna's exalted life to understand the significance of his profound spiritual experiences](https://englishbooks.rkmm.org/s/tsr/m/sri-ramakrishna-life-and-teachings/a/cover)
- [TALES AND PARABLES OF SRI RAMAKRISHNA](https://englishbooks.rkmm.org/s/tsr/m/tales-and-parables-of-sri-ramakrishna/a/cover)
- [SRI RAMAKRISHNA THE GREAT MASTER by Swami Saradananda - comprehensive, authentic and critical estimate of the life, sadhana, and teachings of Sri Ramakrishna.](https://englishbooks.rkmm.org/s/lsr/m/sri-ramakrishna-the-great-master/a/cover)
- [THE GOSPEL OF SRI RAMAKRISHNA by Mahendranath Gupa, translated by Swami Nikhilananda](https://englishbooks.rkmm.org/s/tsr/m/gospel-of-sri-ramakrishna/a/cover-1)